# Mysql using coalece within update statement

Tags: mysql, coalesce

How would I use coalesce within an update statement. All example I have seen use select statement.

```
UPDATE d.n n JOIN d.o o ON n.ID = o.ID SET n.OC = o.OC
```

need n.oc to `Coalesce( n.oc,0)` but Sql failed

```
CALL SQLExecute(CONCAT('UPDATE d.n  n JOIN data.o_ o ON n.id = o.id SET COALESCE(n.OC, null) = o.OC' ));
```

Comment: failed how? which error message?

Comment: for the right syntax to use near '( n.OC, null) = o.OC' at line 1 (1064)

Comment: Emmm! Do you use in form UPDATE d.n n JOIN d.o o ON n.ID = o.ID SET coalesce(n.OC,0) = o.OC ?!!!

Comment: Please show the exact query you are running that generates that error.

Comment: yes.  thats it, should that work? see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query `UPDATE d.n  n JOIN data.o_ o ON n.id = o.id SET COALESCE(n.OC, null) = o.OC`
 does not make sense. `COALESCE(x,y)` uses x if x is not null, otherwise it uses y.

So your query should be

```
UPDATE d.n  n JOIN data.o_ o ON n.id = o.id SET n.OC = o.OC //if null allowed
```

or this

```
UPDATE d.n  n JOIN data.o_ o ON n.id = o.id SET n.OC = COALESCE(o.OC,'somevalue') //if null not allowed
```

Comment: ok, I should have used coalesce old data not new, thanks, but, col oc still has nulls that I want to clean up.

Comment: i just delete where oc is null

Comment: @user428862: if you want to not update n.OC when o.OC is NULL, add a WHERE clause `WHERE o.OC IS NOT NULL`.  If, after that query, there are still n.OC that are NULL, you can either delete them or set them to 'somevalue'.

Comment: thnk, using two sql statements. 2nd deletes its easier.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my. You CAN'T update function!

```
SET n.OC = COALESCE(o.OC, 0)
```

at least